# How does SELECTing from a table scale with table size?

Tags: database, postgresql

When I am searching for rows satisfying a certain condition:

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE type = 5;
```

Is it a linear difference in time when I am executing this query on a table containing 10K and 10M of rows?

In other words - is making this kind of queries on a 10K table 1000 times faster than making it on a 10M table?

My table contains a column `type` which contains numbers from `1` to `10`. The most often query on this table will be the one above. If the difference in performance is true, I will have to make 10 tables for each type to achieve a better performance. If this is not really the issue, I will have two tables - one for the `types`, and the second one for data with column `type_id`.

**EDIT:**
There are multiple rows with the `type` value.

Comment: Are there separate dealers for red cars and black cars? Do you want separate personnel files for males and females?

Comment: This highly depends on the distribution of the data and the indexes in place. If you have a unique index on that column the retrieval costs are almost constant. If there are multiple rows with that value, then yes the retrieval cost will increase with the data volume. This site is really helpful to understand how indexes help in relational databases: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: @wildplasser actually these will be huge tables for awards in the film industry, TV shows, games, etc. So I can have separate tables for each type of awards (in fact I will always be interested in only one table) or gather them all.

Comment: But if you want *all* the awards that Humphrey Bogart has earned, you'll have to search ten tables instead of only one.

Comment: BTW: for low-cardianality attributes, partitioning *can* be an option. But for small tables (10M records actually is small) it would be premature optimization IMnsHO. First get your data model correct by normalising it ( :=removing redandancy) Probably some kind of start-model would arise. After that, *maybe* reshuffle things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer originally tagged [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) and this answer is in those terms. Other DBMSes will vary.)

Like with most super broad questions, "it depends".

If there's no index present, then time is probably roughly linear, though with a nearly fixed startup cost plus some breakpoints - e.g. from when the table fits in RAM to when it no longer fits in RAM. All sorts of effects can come into play - memory banking and NUMA, disk readahead, parallelism in the underlying disk subsystem, fragmentation on the file system, MVCC bloat in the tables, etc - that make this *far* from simple.

If there's a b-tree index on the attribute in question time is going to increase at a less than linear rate - [probably around `O(log n)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). How much less with vary based on whether the index fits in RAM, whether the table fits in RAM, etc. However, PostgreSQL usually then has to do a *heap lookup* for each index pointer, which adds random I/O cost rather unpredictably depending on the data distribution/clustering, caching and readahead, etc. It might be able to do an index-only scan, in which case this secondary lookup is avoided, if vacuum is running enough.

So ... in *extremely* simplified terms, no index = `O(n)`, with index ~= `O(log n)`. Very, very approximately.

I think the underlying intent of the question is along the lines of: *Is it faster to have 1000 tables of 1000 rows, or 1 table of 1,000,000 rows?*. If so: In the great majority of cases the single bigger table will be the better choice for performance and administration.